Number of parameters to specify density matrix
Basic question that is bugging me.
In order to specify a general density matrix on a Hilbert space of dimension $d$ we would need $d^2-1$ real parameters ($d^2$ since the density matrix is hermitian and one less free parameter since we force the trace to be one).
A general state in our Hilbert space needs $2d-2$ real parameters to be specified
($d$ complex components for each independent basis vector and $-2$ since we have normalized the state and don't care about the global phase).
A pure state should then be parameterized by $2d-2$ real parameters but the corresponding density matrix seems to have $2d^2-2$ free parameters (since we get one more constraint by the purity ($\mathrm{Tr}\,\rho^2=1$).
What is going wrong in the above argument?

If $\psi=\sum\limits_{n=1}^d c_n, \psi_n$ (expressed in some orthonormal basis), then $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ in that basis is $\rho_{nm}=c_n c_m^* = |c_n| |c_m| e^{i\varphi_n}e^{-i\varphi_m}$, so to specify the whole matrix you need $d-1$ real parameters (the $|c_n|$ - normalization) +  $d-1$ real parameters (the phases - one arbitrary phase which you can set to 0/which amounts to the arbitrariness of the global phase), hence in total $2d-2$ real parameters.

Nice and straightforward, my problem is trying to explain where the additional $2(d^2-d)$ parameters disapear when it seems that we only need one extra condition to specify that the density matrix is pure.

I see. I guess the takeaway is that the purity condition is not just a single condition, but instead imposes non-trivial conditions on all matrix elements. Indeed, being pure is equivalent to $\rho^2 =\rho \Longleftrightarrow \mathrm{Tr}\rho^2=1$.

Yes exactly, I did not realize that there was an equivalence between being pure and having an idempotent density matrix

In fact it seems that the condition $\rho^2 = \rho$ generates exactly $2d(d-1)$ independent constraints on the off-diagonal elements of the density matrix. Together with the extra condition on the trace of $\rho^2$ is 1, yields exactly $2d-2$ real parameters left as expected.

Nice. Do you mind writing an answer yourself? (I am interested, but also for potential future readers).

A density matrix is an normalized Hermitean matrix, which is can be diagonalized. This means it can be decomposed on a diagonal matrix with $r$ distinct real non-zero eigenvalues (in the case of a pure state, $r=1$) and the rotation matrices with complex numbers. These rotation matrices are composed of $r$ complex orthogonal eigenvectors. Thus we need to sum the $r$ real eigenvalues of the diagonal matrix and the $(2d - 1)r - r^2$ that come from these $r$ orthogonal complex eigenvectors, where $d$ is the dimension of the Hilbert space.
Thus in total we have $2dr - r^2 - 1$ real parameters. Again, if $r = 1$, which is the case for a pure state, then we have $2d-2$ parameters, as you predicted.

You say that a pure density matrix has $1-1=0$ distinct eigenvalues? Is there a typo? I mean a pure density matrix has two distinct eigenvalues, no? Namely $0$ and $1$ (the latter is non-degenerate, while the former is degenerate).

It was a typo, thanks.
